# Ubuntu USB Tethering With Asus ZenFone

Tags: android, ubuntu, usb, tethering

I recently worked through how to get USB tethering to work with my Asus ZenFone for my Ubuntu computer. I wanted to share the wealth.

Comment: I'm getting only 120Kbps speed when tethering over USB, but the phone has high speed internet. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

1. Under *Settings* -> *Storage* -> *USB* select *MTP mode*. Nothing will happen except the device will show up when you run `lsusb` on the desktop. Note the vendor and product IDs listed when you run the command. For   example, if it lists "ID 0b05:5490 ASUSTek Computer, Inc." then 0b05 is the vendor ID and 5490 is the product ID.
2. Run the command: `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0b05 product=0x5490` substituting your values if they are different.
3. Finally on the phone go to *Settings* -> *More* -> *Tethering*, and the *USB Tethering* option should be available. Enable that option and a mobile networking connection should show up in the desktop network manager.
4. To make this change permanent, run this command:

   ```
   sudo echo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0b05 product=0x5490 > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-zenfone.rules
   ```